# what does 'scaling node to multiple instances' mean

Tags: node.js, nginx, web-applications

I've been building a web app in node (and have built others in asp.net-mvc) and recently trying to understand the concept of scaling an app to many users. Assuming a web app gets thousands (or millions) of concurrent users, I understand that the load should be split to more than one instance of node.

my question is, do all these instances run on the same server (virtual machine)? if so, do they (should they) access the same database? if so, does this mean (if I use nginx) that ngingx would be responsible for routing the different requests to the different node instances?

and assuming uploaded files are saved on the file system, do the different instances access the same directories? if not, if a person uploads images to the file system, and connects later and is routed to a different instance of node, how does he access the images he uploaded earlier? is there some sort of sync process done to the file systems?

any resources/articles regarding this would be very helpful!

Comment: Multiple instances of Node *can* run on the same server, but they don't have to. All instances usually access the same database, and the database could be sharded across multiple servers as well, but in some special cases, even using a different database for a different instance of Node is technically possible. There's no real answer to this, you can set this up in just about any conceivable way you want.

Comment: @adeneo i see, thanks for the clarification! what about the uploaded files on the file system? same as the database situation?

Comment: That depends on the setup, uploaded files could be stored in a sharded database, or in a fileserver, like an AWS S3 instance or something, that all Node instances can access, or directly in the filesystem, but that would generally require all intances of Node running on the same server, or at least somehow having access to the same file system.

Comment: Not exactly what you were asking but since you seem to want to educate yourself. This is something that might interest you as well: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster